# How can we create a context file from an existing database, including only those tables accessible to the user 'Programmatically' in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We will only be having database name in string. We need to get the tables in the DB (which are accessible) make a context file containing those tables mapped using DBSet. If we can even list the tables a user can access then also I can make a file creator which can make a context file manually. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which database provider are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In package manager console you can run

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "yourDatabaseString" -Provider "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"
```

for that you need to have EF tools installed, which can be done with

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

If you don't have visual studio, it can be done using dotnet CLI as well.See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: Thank you for such fast and accurate reply.